# Is there a LINQ Query Provider for querying C# files?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there such a thing as a LINQ Query Provider for querying C# files?

I have a Winforms app that I use to assist me in generating code as well as to supplement Visual Studio's editing capabilities for existing code.  One thing I would like to be able to do is to query a given class to see if a method exists.  Or query for a list of classes, or query for classes with a particular `type` in the method signature, etc.

Further, I would love to be able to run the usual CRUDs on said C# files, but I realize that this may be out of scope for this question.

## SOLVED!

Thanks to the folks who suggested [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx), and especially thanks to the code sample provided by Konrad Kokosa below, I was able to get exactly what I needed.

First thing you need to do is download the Roslyn DLLs (I used NuGet).  Then query away.  Here is another example for getting an alphabetized list of all methods in a class:

```
static List<string> GetMethodList(string filename, string className)
{
    var syntaxTree = SyntaxTree.ParseFile(filename);
    var root = syntaxTree.GetRoot();
    var @class = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().FirstOrDefault(md => md.Identifier.ValueText.Equals(className));
   
    return (List<string>) @class.DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().ToList().OrderBy(m => m.Identifier.ValueText).Select(m => m.Identifier.ValueText);
}
```

Comment: You're looking for Roslyn (or for Reflection if you want to run on binaries rather than source).  Beware that C# is a very complicated language; beware of issues like nested generic overloaded types (eg, `A<X>.B` and `A.B<X>` are two different types)

Comment: @SLaks--thanks, reading about Roslyn now (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx).  I appreciate the warning as well, but I think my use will be pretty basic.  It will also be useful for generating documentation, etc.

Comment: `I have a Winforms app that I use to assist me in editing code` - That's called Visual Studio 9.0, after that came Visual Studio 10.0 which is no longer winforms

Comment: Yes, I am also curious why you need such an app. Perhaps we could solve your code generation needs (such as with T4, emitting IL, DLR or other tools) rather than helping you reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @allonguralnek Agree 100%.

Comment: @HighCore--I have edited the question to more accurately reflect my meaning.

Comment: See @allonGuralnek's comment. You're basically reinventing the wheel, seemingly.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek-- I use T4 templates, and do like them.  However, there are certain other uses for the app I have written.  For example, I can generate both my entity layer and DAL classes/methods with a button press, provided that I already have a valid SQL architecture for it to reference.  It just works well for me, but maybe not everyone.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt that's called [Entity Framework DB-first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx). Yes, you're effectively reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @HighCore--I am very familiar with DB first as well.  You are going to just have to take my word for it--the app is useful to me.  Anyway this question is regarding a LINQ query provider for C# files, not the reason behind my needing it

Comment: BTW, your `ToList()` call is useless.

Comment: @Slaks--Hmmmm--if I am returning an IEnumerable, you are correct: I can remove the cast and the convert.  However, if I remove the convert when attempting to return a `List<string>` I get an `unable to cast object. . .` error.  I agree it looks strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found Roslyn very intuitive. Here is an example of parsing source file for a specified `methodName` within specified class `className`:

```
static void GetClassMethod(string filename, string className, string methodName)
{
    var syntaxTree = SyntaxTree.ParseFile(filename);
    var root = syntaxTree.GetRoot();
    var @class = root.DescendantNodes()
                      .OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>()
                      .Where(md => md.Identifier.ValueText.Equals(className))
                      .FirstOrDefault();
    var method = @class.DescendantNodes()
                      .OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>()
                      .Where(md => md.Identifier.ValueText.Equals(methodName))
                      .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

From this example you can easily build querying all classes withing a file.

Comment: This worked beautifully!  Thanks for the code sample!  Also, thanks for NOT worrying about what my motivations are.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft is working on a project called Roslyn which allows you to interact with C# code via ordinary .NET objects:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx

It hasn't been officially released, though, and I'm honestly not sure that it would include things like manipulating the source files (for example, to add a function to a class).

If you're working with code that is already compiled, you could probably use a combination of a few tricks, such as loading an assembly at runtime and then using reflection to interrogate it.

However, I would suggest taking a look at tools that are already available for generating code, like [T4 Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx). There might be a better way to solve the underlying problem than interrogating C# source files.

Comment: Roslyn is the underlying technology used for the refactoring engine in Visual Studio, so yes, it will be able to do anything that the refactoring engine can do, such as extracting a statement into a new method of a class.

Comment: In particular, Roslyn gives you a full tree of your entire source, and lets you modify it however you like.

Comment: To clarify SLaks' point slightly: the tree is immutable, but there are methods that mean "give me a new tree based on this tree, but with the following change..."